# UITableView - methods are not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a subview in which I build a UITableview, I've set the delegate and datasource to the subview but for some reason the table methods are not being called...can someone look over my code and see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

.h file

```
@interface TwitterController : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> { 

UIButton* btnCloseView; 
UITableView* tblTweets;
UIImageView* imgTwitterIcon;

ColorController* colorManager;

NSMutableArray* tweetsArray;
NSMutableArray* tableData;

NSString* twitterID;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* twitterID;

- (NSMutableArray* ) getTweets; 

- (void) sendNotification : (id) sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "TwitterController.h"

@implementation TwitterController

@synthesize twitterID;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    colorManager = [ColorController new];

}
return self;
}


/*- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {



}*/

- (void)layoutSubviews { 

imgTwitterIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTwitterBird"]];
CGRect twitterIconFrame = [imgTwitterIcon frame];
twitterIconFrame.origin.x = 50.0;
twitterIconFrame.origin.y = 20.0;

tblTweets = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 25.0, 220.0, 500.0)];
tblTweets.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
tblTweets.separatorColor = [colorManager setColor:176.0:196.0:222.0];
tblTweets.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
tblTweets.rowHeight = 20.0;
tblTweets.scrollEnabled = YES;
tblTweets.delegate = self;
tblTweets.dataSource = self;

tableData = [self getTweets];

UIImage* imgCloseButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCloseWindow.png"];
CGSize imageSize = imgCloseButton.size;
btnCloseView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(220.0, 550.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
[btnCloseView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCloseWindow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCloseView addTarget:self action:@selector(sendNotification:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[self addSubview:tblTweets];
[self addSubview:imgTwitterIcon];
[self addSubview:btnCloseView];
}

- (NSMutableArray*) getTweets { 

//array to hold tweets
tweetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

twitterID = @"Pruit_Igoe";

///set up a NSURL to the twitter API
NSURL* twitterAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=%@&count=10", twitterID]];

//get last 10 tweets (max is 20)
TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:twitterAPI 
            parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

// Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
[twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200)  {

        // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
        // Move the response into a dictionary and print
        NSError *error;        
        NSDictionary *tweetsDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

        for(NSDictionary* thisTweetDict in tweetsDict) { 

            [tweetsArray addObject:[thisTweetDict objectForKey:@"text"]];
        }

    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
}];

return tweetsArray;


}

#pragma mark Table Management

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [tableData count];
NSLog(@"%i", [tableData count]); //does not log!
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    {
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:66.0/255.0 blue:66.0/255.0 alpha:1];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 13.0];
cell.textLabel.text = [tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGRect cellFrame = [cell frame];
cellFrame.size.height = 25.0;

return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString* thisTweet = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark Close Window

- (void) sendNotification : (id) sender { 

NSMutableDictionary* userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[userData setObject:@"closeTwitter" forKey:@"theEvent"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theMessenger" object:self userInfo: userData];

}

@end
```

Comment: have you alloc and init your tblTweets?

Comment: he does - but in `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not allocate and initialize `tableData`. Write it    `tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method or `- (void)layoutSubviews` method. Just try it.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
NSLog(@"%i", [tableData count]);
return [tableData count];
//NSLog(@"%i", [tableData count]); //does not log!
}
```

If the output is zero, `tableData` array is empty. Check it `tableData` array

Comment: You're rigt, i missed that one.

Comment: if tweetArray is allocated/init and being returned from getTweets do I have to alloc/init tableData? I thought I didn't have to. I added the alloc/init to my code but nothing changed.

Comment: output isn't 0, there is no output at all. in - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [tableData count];
NSLog(@"%i", [tableData count]); //does not log!
} it doesn't log at all.

Comment: Write  'NSLog(@"%i", [tableData count]);' before ' return [tableData count];'. It will work.

Comment: Duh. : D Yep, getting 0, but the array has 10 items in it.

Comment: Where did you allocate and initialize tableDate?

Answer (score 0):

You should do all the initialization (`tblTweets` for example) in `initWithFrame:`.

`layoutSubviews` is ment for laying out subviews.

In fact your code will (should) work if you move all the code `fromLayoutSubviews` to `initWithFrame:`. You can then move parts of the code (the laying out part) back.

EDIT: when you move initializing code you will probably also have to add `[tblTweets reloadData];` right after `tableData = [self getTweets];`

Comment: Is that for performance reasons or best practices for code organization? Would I add the UITableView in the init or in layoutSubviews then? i.e - (void) layoutSubviews { [self addSubview tblTweets]; } ?

Comment: Any clue as to why the table data is not loading? : )

Comment: `layoutSubviews` might get called many more times during the app execution - that's the main reason. I'll check about loading.

Comment: I'm looking at docs and Apple suggest viewDidLoad for adding subviews: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

Comment: This kind of `layoutSubviews` implementation is typically used in more complex subclasses of `UIVIew`. You definetly shouldn't init and add tblTweets in that place. Each time it would be called your tableView would be reinitialized.

Comment: OK, so now back to my original question - why aren't the table methods being called?

Comment: Prasad gave a good pointer - it seems your tableData is not initialized.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind would be: do you have a really good reason for subclassing `UIView` instead of `UIViewController`. `UIViewController` would seems like a **much more appropriate** class to subclass for what it seems you're trying to do. I'd really recommend going this way.

Comment: I thought rule of thumb was UIViewController for full screen, UIView if not, this is for an iPad and it's not full screen...

Comment: Not really - ´UIViewController´ is perfectly good in smaller dimensions. And you get to use all that `loadView`,`viewDidLoad`,`viewWillAppear`... methods. Sorry that i didn't notice/mention this before.